# RXJS combineLatest and mergemap

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'd like to unsubscribe from (and reinitialise) an Observable returned by a function every time a combinelatest function triggers.

In the example below myObservableFunction would fire and create a subscription, but any previous subscriptions to the function would also exist. Any ideas how to have only one sub to the function at any time?

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    streamOne$,
    streamTwo$
)
.mergeMap(() => myObservableFunction()) 
.subscribe(() => console.log("hello!")
```

Comment: Use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`